# Requirements gathering questionarie templete

Tags: web-applications, requirements

I have a client who ask me to redesign his e-learning website,and we had a first call he explained everything about his website.Now how I prepare a questionnaire template for asking him about all the functionalities in the website and about the design of the website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by asking what frameworks they are currently using (jQuery, Vue...) and what the backend setup is like (static, NodeJs, php...). From there you can ask where he wants to go with the website and what he wants done.

Comment: @sample much like you just asked. Something like "now that I understand the technologies involved, what functionality is present that you want improved, and what functionality is lacking that you desired?" Then you can ask them to prioritize the features and functionality they care the most about.